# ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home

Tags: ruby

I am new coder - just learning how to use Ruby through a one month intro course. I know my question has been asked but all the answers seem to advanced for someone starting out like me. I am hoping someone can walk me through simple way of resolving this. I am using windows 10 and Rails version: 5.1.2
Ruby version: 2.3.3 (i386-mingw32)

I am working on my first Ruby project and when I try to run 'rails generate controller home pages', I am getting the following when I try to load localhttp://localhost:3000/pages/home

ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home
Showing c:/Users/Mariam/Desktop/pinteresting/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?